# django read json file with relative file path

Tags: django

I am attempting to deploy django in production, but have an issue with a relative file path in my models.py.

When I use python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000, the site works fine. When I run django using http and wsgi, I get the error that the below file cannot be found. I assume this is because it is looking for the file using a relative path. How should I fix this?

This is the line in my models.py, which imports the json file.

```
data = open('orchestration/static/router_models.json').read()
```

Answer (score 0):

its better to store the file in your model (file field).

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is how I have solved it.  from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
p = staticfiles_storage.path('router_models.json')
data = open(p).read()